# if we print data directly within page by php OR by using php api(json) but print using ajax which one is faster

Tags: php, json, ajax, api

i want to know which one is more faster/reliable  or compact if we drive data from mysql and make json code of it and fetch it through ajax and print it or we directly print data in a web page.so please tell me in detail.

Comment: `AJAX` is little faster because, Its carrying data only (Not resources like CSS/JS). But your should load the page (Layout) to render the AJAX response on Page. In your case, To get larger number of data from MySQL, `AJAX` is good option. Because, You can chunk all data without refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for more information